# There was a problem with cartographer mapping with ros1

Tags: ros, python, lidar, 2d-mapping, cartographer

I'm trying to map one track using a cartographer using ROS1, but there was a continuous problem with the track being twisted track.

The lidar used is Hokuyo UST-10LX.
The map we're going to measure is as follows.[image]
If we map this to the lidar we have, we get the following results.[image]
The launch file is as follows:

[image]

.lua file is as follows:

```
include "map_builder.lua"

  include "trajectory_builder.lua"

​
  options = {

   map_builder = MAP_BUILDER,

   trajectory_builder = TRAJECTORY_BUILDER,

   map_frame = "map",

   tracking_frame = "base_link",

   published_frame = "base_link",

   odom_frame = "odom",

   provide_odom_frame = true,

   use_odometry = true,

   use_nav_sat = false,

   num_laser_scans = 1,

   num_multi_echo_laser_scans = 0,

   num_subdivisions_per_laser_scan = 1,

   num_point_clouds = 0,

   lookup_transform_timeout_sec = 0.2,

   submap_publish_period_sec = 0.5,

   pose_publish_period_sec = 5e-3,

   trajectory_publish_period_sec = 30e-3,

   rangefinder_sampling_ratio = 1.,

   odometry_sampling_ratio = 0.3,

   fixed_frame_pose_sampling_ratio = 1.,

   imu_sampling_ratio = 1.,

   use_landmarks = false,

   publish_frame_projected_to_2d = false,

   publish_tracked_pose = true,

   landmarks_sampling_ratio = 1.,

  
 }

​
 MAP_BUILDER.use_trajectory_builder_2d = true

 MAP_BUILDER.use_trajectory_builder_3d = false

 MAP_BUILDER.num_background_threads = 5.0

 TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.use_imu_data = false

 TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.max_range = 15

 TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.min_range = 0.1

 --TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.num_accumulated_range_data = 1

 TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.ceres_scan_matcher.translation_weight = 2e2

 TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.ceres_scan_matcher.rotation_weight = 4e2

 ​
 --TRAJECTORY_BUILDER.pure_localization_trimmer = {
    -- max_submaps_to_keep = 10,
 --}
 -- might be able to optimize these parameters
 -- see: http://google-cartographer- 
 ros.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tuning.html
 TRAJECTORY_BUILDER_2D.submaps.num_range_data = 100
 POSE_GRAPH.optimize_every_n_nodes = 20
​
 return options
```

The following warning appears in the terminal window during the LiDAR mapping process, so the reason for that warning seems to be the problem.
[image]

I want a way to fix that error and LiDAR to fully map the track.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Robotics StackExchange! It is always better to upload the source code of the file instead of a screenshot (your launch file seems to be a screenshot), so that we can search through it. :)

Comment: Also, by looking at the map, it seems like you have some sort of a drift. I'd suggest to inspect the data coming out of your `imu` and `odom` topics. You might find an inconsistency there somewhere. Look for sudden jumps in values.

Comment: Immediately after posting the source code of the file, I checked it and found that it sometimes did not appear in the post. I uploaded it as a screenshot to solve this problem, but I'll try again. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Cutting and pasting the error/warning message text instead of screenshots helps with readability and allows others to search for this post more easily.  The launch file text should work if you select it and press the `{}` Code Sample button to indent it.